# Variance of Ordered, PartiallyOrdered

Tags: scala, variance

According to the documentation, `PartiallyOrdered[A]` is covariant in `A`, while `Ordered[A]` is invariant (but used to be covariant) in `A`.

Why was `Ordered[A]` ever covariant in `A`? Isn't this an obvious violation of the substitution principle?

Why can't `Ordered[A]` be contravariant in `A`? This would allow an `Ordered[Traversible[Char]]` to be typed as an `Ordered[StringBuilder]`, for example. I don't see how this could be problematic.

<strike>I'm having trouble understanding the signature of `tryCompareTo` in [`PartiallyOrdered`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.math.PartiallyOrdered). It looks like the argument can be an instance of any supertype of `A`. Couldn't you pass in any object by calling `tryCompareTo[Any](anything)`? If so, how is the method signature any better than `tryCompareTo(that: Any)`?</strike>

Logically, ordered sets are a subclass of partially ordered sets, but the Scala classes don't seem to reflect this relationship. Is this because `Ordered[A]` cannot be covariant in `A` as `PartiallyOrdered[A]` can?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [previous version (2.8.1)](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.8.1/scala/math/Ordered.html) , I didn't find anything relevant about `Ordered` that was covariant ?

**EDIT** : Looked further and find some [explanation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.7.7/scala/Ordered.html) in the documentation for `Ordered` to not be covariant anymore.

For the case of `tryCompare` in `PartiallyOrdered`, the signature set more restriction on passed parameter :

```
def tryCompareTo [B >: A] (that: B)(implicit arg0: (B) ⇒ PartiallyOrdered[B]): Option[Int]
```

Here the implicit `arg0` implies `that` to be seen as a `PartiallyOrdered[B]` instance and thus that it has access to all method defined in this trait.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess I understand tryCompareTo, after staring for the signature for a little while. Any insights on the variance of Ordered[A], though?

Comment: I won't edit yet the answer because I'm not sure about this point but I think it is because you can't be sure that `Ordered[A]` is equals to `Ordered[B]` even if `B <: A`. More details in this [extract from Programming in Scala](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/object-equality.html)